# CSS Keyframes Transition pauses when using scale

Tags: css, css-animations

I have the following code:

```
@keyframes sonar-wave {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1.00);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    50% {
        transform: scale(1.15);
        opacity: 0.5;
    }

    100% {
        transform: scale(1.3);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

When this triggers, I see a "pause" before the scale continues.  I would like a smooth scaling animation.  Fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lztxfho9/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you didn't specify a [`timing function`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-timing-function.asp), So the browser will default to `ease`

change it to

```
animation: sonar-wave 2s linear forwards;
```